# Adding multiple pairs of arguments, parser

Tags: python, argparse

I want to be able to add in multiple pairs of start and end dates as arguments, but I'm not sure how.

Currently my code looks like:

```
if __name__ = "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--start_date', type = str)
    parser.add_argument('--end_date', type = str)
    stdin_args = parser.parse_args()
    do_function(...)
```

But I want to be able to add multiple pairs of start and end dates, with an argument like `n_date_pairs`, taking an integer as the number of pairs of dates I want to input. So for example,

```
python main.py --n_date_pairs 3 --start_date_1 2020-01-02 --end_date_1 2020-01-04 --start_date_2 2021-03-24 --end_date_2 2021-04-01 --start_date_3 2021-07-01 --end_date_3 2021-07-05
```

How can I add this?

Comment: you can define some custom format string type argument, then parse that string. no need rely on the module built in mechanism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic arguments for Python's argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317795/dynamic-arguments-for-pythons-argparse)

Comment: If you specify `action='append'` and repeat the arguments you'll get lists that you can iterate through.

Comment: How about just an argument `--date_ranges` and assign multiple date ranges to it.  E.g. `--date_ranges 2020-01-02/2020-01-04 2021-03-24/2021-04-01 2021-07-01/2021-07-05`.  To have multiple values just `add_argument('--date_ranges', nargs='*')`.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I'd use a list of pairs for data like what you are describing.  Then iterate through the list.  Here's a toy example:

```
list_of_date_pairs = [['2020-01-02', '2020-01-04'], ['2021-03-24', '2021-04-01'], ['2021-07-01', '2021-07-05']]

for st, end in list_of_date_pairs:
    parser.add_argument(st)
    parser.add_argument(end)
```

Comment: you're not using command line argument, which is the OP's point.